# How to split long sed expression into multiple lines?

Tags: sed

```
sed 's/[long1][long2]/[long3][long4]/' file.txt
```

I would like to split this command onto multiple lines - f.x. something like this:

```
sed 's/
    [long1]
    [long2]
  /
    [long3]
    [long4]
  /' file.txt
```

Using `\` or separating strings didn't work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8078872/can-a-long-sed-command-be-broken-over-several-lines

Comment: That's why Perl has the `/x` modifier to substitution.

Comment: @Networker: yes, thanks, I added my answer there, too

Comment: Just to point out: this question is not about sed at all. It is about how to correctly break a line in a terminal command. (Note: I don't mean to say there is anything wrong with the question. However, a retagging may be well worth consideration. - Or at least adding one or two other relevant tags ...)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
sed 's'/\
'[long1]'\
'[long2]'\
'/'\
'[long3]'\
'[long4]'\
'/' file.txt
```

Splitting on several lines with backslash does work if new lines are not indented.

```
$ echo "a,b" | sed 's/\(.'\
> '\),\(.\)/\2-\1/'
b-a
```

Tested on Cygwin with GNU sed 4.2.2

Comment: _Splitting on several lines with backslash does work if new lines are not indented._ That did it for me. Thanks and cheers! :-)

Answer (score 14):

Another aspect:

How maintainable are the `[long]` items above?

The shorter and more distinct you can keep the clauses, the easier they will be to change and enhance as time passes and (sed-external) facts change around the the function they provide.

e.g.

```
sed \
-e 's/[minimal-s1]/[minimal-r1]/' \
-e 's/[minimal-s2]/[minimal-r2]/' \
-e 's/[minimal-s3]/[minimal-r3]/' \
-e 's/[minimal-s4]/[minimal-r4]/'
```

... might be something to strive for and prefer.

Comment: I like this answer.  It's useful to know though that because you're breaking up everything into their own arguments, an indent will work fine on the subsequent lines.

Answer (score 9):

You can save long string to bash variables, then use in `sed` command:

```
string=[long1][long2]
replace=[long3][long4]
sed -e 's/'"$string"'/'"$replace"'/' file
```

If you can use `perl`, you can break long pattern with `x` modifier:

```
perl -e 's/
[long1]
[long2]
/[long3][long4]/x' file
```

Comment: Why do you use so many quotes? `sed "s/$string/$replace/" file.txt` is fine.

Comment: @alife: Um, yeah, OK, but … why?  Does it ever make more sense to say `echo 'c'"a"'t'` rather than `echo "cat"`, when you know that `c`, `a` and `t` are not special characters? I’m not questioning his use of *some* quotes, I’m saying he uses more than he needs. Can you give an example of `string` and `replace` where `'s/'"$string"'/'"$replace"'/'` works but `"s/$string/$replace/"` doesn’t? His answer will still fail if `string` or `replace` contains a slash.

Answer (score 7):

You can also break that up this way:

```
sed '/[long1][long2]/
    s//[long3][long4]/'
```

Or maybe like:

```
sed "$(
    printf 's/[%s][%s]/[%s][%s]/' \
        long1 \
        long2 \
        long3 \
        long4
)"
```

Or with a heredoc:

```
sed -f - <<SED file.txt
s/\
[long1]\
[long2]\
/\
[long3]\
[long4]\
/
SED
```