# How to break sed commands to nested parts when no regex and variable expansions are applied?

Tags: sed

I want to replace all occurrences of a particular, previously-determined (known) email address --- with another email address, inside a PHP file; no regex should be involved ; `sed` is the simplest way I know to do so.

This worked (the email has been changed):

```
sed -i 's/\$to = "example@example.com"/\$to = "example_1@example_1.com"/g' FILE
```

But I think it's generally wrong to do text processing with one liners especially if one finds them "too long", so I tried to break it to the following which doesn't work:

```bsh
sed -i \
' \
-e s/
-e \$to = "example@example.com"/
-e \$to = "example_1@example_1.com"/
-e g
' \
FILE
```

> `sed: -e expression #1, char 8: unterminated address regex`

How to break sed commands to nested parts when no regex and variable expansions are applied?
(i.e. when no regex and variable expansions / special quoting rules are part of the operation)

Comment: 1. `\$to = "example@example.com"` **is** a regular expression, even if it is only a very simple one.   The `s//` operator matches on regular expressions, not fixed strings, even if they look kind of like fixed strings.  2. you can't do this with sed, but perl has `/x` and `/xx` regex modifiers to allow using whitespace (and comments) to make regular expressions more readable.  See `man perlre` and search for "Details on some modifiers".

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146955/how-to-split-long-sed-expression-into-multiple-lines for a number of ways of splitting long `sed` commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
sed -i \
's/'\
'\$to = "example@example.com"'\
'/'\
'\$to = "example1@example1.com"'\
'/g'\
 FILE
```

Note the single space before `FILE`